# NUnit tests are not restarted through VSTest in DevOps

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, nunit, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I am using VSTest to run tests via Azure DevOps. Tests run successfully, but using the option `rerun failed tests: true`, an error appears during the restart phase.

NUnit 3.12.0 ;
NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0 (Checked with 4.0.0.0)

```
vstest.console.exe "C:\agent2.172.2\_work\r1\a\UITest\drop\Tests.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\Tests.Web.dll"
/Settings:"C:\agent2.172.2\_work\_temp\3utv233tymm.runsettings"
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent2.172.2\_work\r1\a\UITest\drop\Tests.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1"
/TestCaseFilter:"FullyQualifiedName=Tests.Web.Tests._5.CourierModuleTest.N1_SendingTest.Id_5_1_01_TransferToCourierModule(Chrome)|FullyQualifiedName=Tests.Web.Tests._3.IssuanceOfDocuments.InformationOnTheApplicationIdentificationOfRecipient.N2_RecipientIdentificationTest.Id_3_2_13_RegisterAddressByFiasTest(Chrome)"
NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test execution started
An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://nunit3testexecutor/': Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&'. Specify the correct format and try again. Note that the incorrect format can lead to no test getting executed.
```

How can I fix this error and successfully restart the tests in DevOps?

I tried googling for a similar issue but didn't find anything that would work. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's [similar discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7037), according to comments from the Contributors of [azure-pipelines-task repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks):

1.You should update your VS and VSTest component within it to latest version since we don't support data driven tests for Rerun scenario. It will be available with VS 15.8 release and higher.

2.You should configure your VSTest task following [this solution](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7037#issuecomment-410140363):

[image]

Recommended to give total number of your tests as input (`Number of tests per batch`).